# Displaying Content Menu When Image on RecyclerView Item Clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have design my `RecyclerView` to display something like this:

[image: My RecyclerView]

I want to show context menu when user clicked and `ImageView` (the vertical 3 dots image) in `RecyclerView` item.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VendorViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.nameText.setText(this.vendors.get(position).getName());
    holder.contextMenuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Code to show ContextMenu here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add `ToolBar` in your recycler item and inflate the menu in on `onbindviewholder`

Comment: Can you elaborate this? I'm able to achieve this using `Subin Babu` answer but I'm curious if there's more than one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that 3 dot image and on click of that image use the following,

```
//creating a popup menu
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.addresslistmenu);
//inflating menu from xml resource
popup.inflate(R.menu.addressmenu);
//adding click listener
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.addresslistupdatemenu:
                                yourfunction()
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
//displaying the popup
popup.show();
```

Add the menu item in res-menu,

example  ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/addresslistupdatemenu"
        android:title="Update" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/addresslistdeletemenu"
        android:title="Delete" />
</menu>
```

Image click is in onBindViewHolder in the adapter.

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     // PopupMenu function here
                }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, it work for me. Btw is `PopupMenu` available on Android 5.1?