# How can I set a popup menu against a bottom navigation bar menu item?

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have added a bottom navigation bar to my project as shown below.

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView= 
    (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigationbar);
    pass.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigationbar);
     final Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
     MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {


            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:

                    break;

                case R.id.categories:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, category.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.more:

                   Intent itent6=new Intent(MainActivity.this,more.class);
                    startActivity(itent6);
                    break;
                case R.id.account:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                case R.id.cart:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cart.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I want to add a popup menu when we click on the menu item with id R.id.more.
I have tried a few methods but in most cases I got an error saying that anchor not found.
In other cases the popup did not show at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Content Menu When Image on RecyclerView Item Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746915/displaying-content-menu-when-image-on-recyclerview-item-clicked)

Comment: No, its not the same thing. There the popup has been anchored onto an image button. I want this to be anchored to another menu item, ie, the bottom bar menu item.

Comment: You can add the same concept to your bottom bar menu. Whats difference between the accepted answer and my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be helpful for you.

```
       case R.id.more:
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.more));
                    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();

                    /*Intent itent6=new Intent(MainActivity.this,more.class);
                startActivity(itent6);*/
                    break;
```